# Arduino ESP8266 - Timed out waiting for packet header

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to implement an IoT app with the Arduino UNO clone and ESP8266 wifi module. I followed [this](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/pulasthi-nanayakkara/connecting-esp8266-to-firebase-to-send-receive-data-4adf66) documentation and applied the instructions step by step,
I have all of the related libraries and boards installed but when I tried to upload the sketch, I am getting this error;

```
esptool.py v2.8
Serial port COM6
Connecting........__....._....._....._....._....._.....___Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\OYKU\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.7.4/tools/upload.py", line 65, in <module>
esptool.main(cmdline)
File "C:/Users/OYKU/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 2890, in main
esp.connect(args.before)
File "C:/Users/OYKU/AppData/Local/Arduino15/packages/esp8266/hardware/esp8266/2.7.4/tools/esptool\esptool.py", line 483, in connect
raise FatalError('Failed to connect to %s: %s' % (self.CHIP_NAME, last_error))
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
esptool.FatalError: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
```

[This is the circuit diagram that I've used while uploading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCC99.png).

- I've tried to reinstall all of the libraries, boards, even the Arduino IDE.
- I used FirebaseDEMO example sketch at the start but it didn't work so I tried to upload a blank sketch to see if the problem is in the code.
- I'm using raw ESP8266 module so there is no reset button on my module so I used IO0 pin on board just as in the [diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCC99.png).
- I thought the problem could be in my Arduino, usb cable or in my module but they are working just fine when I'm using standard Arduino UNO board.

I've tried much more solutions but none of them worked for me. I have to finish and deliver this project until next week so I can't order any additional modules so any help would be great for me.

Here is the settings that I'm using;

- [Board settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUrBV.png)
- [Additional Boards Manager URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WADc9.png)

Thanks in advance.